# In an Ajax POST, do I need to urlencode parameters before sending?

Tags: javascript, ajax, urlencode

I have some lengthy JSON text that I am sending back to the server via Ajax:

```
http.open("POST", url, true);
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", myVeryLongAJAXText.length);
http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
http.onreadystatechange = function() {...}
http.send(myVeryLongAJAXText);
```

Do I need to change the last line to:

```
http.send(encodeURI(myVeryLongAJAXText));
```

or does the send method take care of that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to encode them on the client, and decode them on the server. It will work undecoded, but it's less error prone, and safer to encode/decode.

Send doesn't offer that because the data being sent could be just a single integer, so calling UrlEncoding would introduce unneeded overhead.

Answer (score 0):

You should encode them. Send doesn't do this for you.